# Render '.md' files inline using jsdoc?

Tags: jsdoc

typedoc has the ability to render '.md' inline with the generated documentation by linking the markdown files in comments like so:

```
/*
 * [[include:example.md]]
 */
function myFunction() {
}
```

[see typedoc docs here](https://typedoc.org/guides/options/#includes)

I'm looking for a way to emulate this behavior in jsdoc. Any way to reference a markdown file by name in a jsdoc comment and display it inline in the generated html that jsdoc outputs.

Jsdoc has the concept of tutorials where markdown files can be linked in comments but that does not render the markdown. it simply provides a clickable link. Maybe there is a jsdoc template that renders instead of linking?

I have seen this question:
[JSDoc: How to include multiple .md file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071898/jsdoc-how-to-include-multiple-md-file).
I'm looking for a better solution than using jsdoc tutorials.

Comment: I don't understand what's is your question. Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: @Gi1ber7 Thanks for looking. I tried to edit my question to clarify.